# C / Assembly: how to change a single bit in a CPU register?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

I'm a new researcher on the software fault injection field, and currently my ultimate goal is to write a simple piece of code that is able to change a single bit in a CPU register. I was thinking of doing it in C (with some Assembly calls included amongst the code). With that in mind, I found here in Stack Overflow this great thread & simple example on how to access the contents of a 32 bit CPU register: [Is it possible to access 32-bit registers in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022046/is-it-possible-to-access-32-bit-registers-in-c) This way, I was able to write this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    register int value;

    register int ecx asm("ecx");
    printf("Contents of ecx: %d\n", ecx);

    asm("movl %%ecx, %0;" : "=r" (value) : ); //Assembly: this stores the ecx value into the variable value
    printf("Contents of value: %d\n", value);

    return 0;
}
```

This seems to be a great introduction to this theme, and the answers provided there gave me great insight and information sources (I'm already reading the GCC documentation), but now I need to move further, i. e., I need to understand how can I change the contents of a single bit in a CPU register (or at least, to start, something simpler: how can I change a CPU register value?). If someone can give me a hint or tell me the most approriate source to look for it, I'd be deeply grateful.

All the best & thanks in advance,
João

P.S.: Don't know if this helps, but I'm working on a CentOS 6.5 32 bit system (although the CPU is a 64 bit one, more precisely a Intel Pentium Dual CPU E2180 @ 2.00 GHz). Also, I have had previous contact with Assembly, but it was like 10 years ago, on a single course unit for a couple of months, so currently I'm trying to review the little knowledge I have on the language.

Comment: yes, most compilers have provisions to embed assembler inside another language, but exactly how that's done depends on the compiler itself.

Comment: I am not a researcher in the software fault injection field, but I have to wonder about the decision to focus on changing bits in registers.  Why pick on registers instead of variables?  It's possible (if uncommon) for variables to never end up in a register.  That said, gcc allows you to directly access assembly in your code so you can easily stomp on registers if that's your thing (`asm("mov $0, %%eax":)`).  Obviously this kind of thing would ordinarily be a VERY BAD IDEA, but if your goal is to create faults, well, there you go.  To stomp on bits, look at i386 assembly (maybe BTC?).

Comment: I guess that I'm looking into registers because I want to somehow emulate hardware faults via software (i. e., emulate a bit-flip, to start). I'll look forward to your suggestion (i386 Assembly / BTC). Thanks!

Comment: I would use `AND eax, 0xFFFE` to unset the bit 0, `OR eax 0x01` to set bit 0 or `XOR eax, ecx` for bit-flips (with ecx containing eax with some bits masked).

Comment: @dureuill why not just xor with a constant? btw, `and eax, 0xFFFE` resets over half the bits.

Comment: @harold er, you're right, looks like someone did too much 16-bits programming lately... As for the `xor`, I have no excuse, don't know what went wrong inside my head.

Comment: I don't think this would be the best way to go about simulating a hardware fault. Using inline assembly would modify a register at a fixed location in the the program, not a random location like you'd expect for a hardware fault. It also would have an affect on program generation. The compiler is either going to generate different count around the inline assembly or optimize it away because it thinks it has no effect. Using a debugging API (eg. ptrace) to modify a register in another running program should give you something that more resembles a hardware fault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way of modifying a subset of the bits of a register in assembly is to use logical operations with constants.

`AND %eax, 0xFFFFFFFE` unsets the 0th bit.

`OR %eax, 0x01` sets the 0th bit.

`XOR %eax, 0x01` flips the 0th bit.

(thanks @harold for the corrections).

That being said, and as noted in the comments, you probably don't want to directly use inline assembly in the program to simulate hardware faults. It will be tightly bound to the place where you introduced the modification, and mixing fault introduction at the source and at the binary level is not an approach I would recommend (your compiler can and will reorganize and optimize code, so it is likely that it will ultimately lead to unexpected behavior. See . Balakrishnan's and Reps' What You See Is Not What You eXecute).

you could use a binary instrumentation platform such as Intel's PIN or an existing fault injection framework.

**EDIT:**
Since OP asked for a "hello world" example of inline asm in comments, here it is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    register int eax asm("%eax");
    asm("xorl %eax, %eax");
    asm("xorl $1, %eax");
    printf("Content of eax: %d\n", eax);
    return 0;
}
```

Save as test.c then compile with:

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

or better:

```
gcc test.c -S
```

which will create test.s, a file containing the assembly output of your program. This file will let you understand many things about your code, and you should produce the assembly before compiling when using inline asm (at least when there is something you don't understand).

You can then assemble the binary from the assembly with:

```
gcc test.s -o test
```

Here are a few things to note on x86:

- In actual instructions, I put the destination register at the end of the instruction.
- Immediate are prefixed with "$", registers with a "%"
- The instructions that manipulate extended registers (32 bits registers, prefixed with "e") are suffixed with "l"

Comment: Thanks for the insight, dureuill. I understand that this isn't the best way to simulate hardware faults. This is more a starting point for someone who is a newbie on the field (a kind of a "hello world!"). I'm trying to fully understand your useful comments / answer, more precisely your Assembly code, and possibly I'll expose my doubts here. Again, many thanks!

Comment: I've understood better your Assembly now (for people like me that haven't dealt with bitwise / logical operators for years, this can become handy: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)).

In fact, the behaviour of the code below ("Segmentation fault (core dumped)") isn't what I "expected" (probably what you mentioned as "(...) ultimately lead to unexpected behavior"):

`#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 register int eax asm("eax");

 asm("XOR %eax, 0x01");

 //printf("Contents of eax: %d\n", eax_value);

 return 0;
}`

Any hint on this? Thanks!

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, you used the first XOR to set the value of eax to zero,and the second one to make a bit-flip on the same register(0x00000000 to 0x00000001), right? (The output here is "Content of eax: 1") Thanks, I couldn't ask for a better answer :]

Comment: You understood correctly. I'm glad my answer is useful to you.

Comment: Just 2 more questions, if you don't mind: 1. Just added 2 printfs to your code, strangely the last one always gives me the same output, different from the original one:  register int eax asm("%eax");     printf("Initial content of eax: %d\n", eax);     asm("xorl %eax, %eax");     printf("Content of eax after reset: %d\n", eax);     asm("xorl $1, %eax");     printf("Content of eax after bit-flip: %d\n", eax);     return 0; Do you know why this output change happens?

Comment: 2. Now I want to do something more complex, i. e., being able to interrupt the OS and then execute code of mine, like your nice example, for instance, and then be able to access information on the context pre-interrumption. Do you know where can I get more information on this? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: As for your first question I'll just say that printf is using eax, too. As for your second question, you're looking for a binary instrumentation program.

Comment: (just for future reference, as this can also be valuable to someone reading the thread) Meanwhile, I've been looking at Intel Pin (a well-known binary instrumentation program), but it seems it only operates at user level, so it can only instrument applications. This means it can't be used to modify the OS execution, i. e. doesn't support system-wide instrumentation. I'm now looking into other solutions, thanks again for being so helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The Intel-based processors offers instructions to manipulate one bit at a time. These instructions are most often ignored and replaced by the `AND`, `OR`, `XOR`, and `TEST` instructions which can manipulate multiple bits at once. Also older processors would be *really* slow executing them. I do not know whether they are still slow, probably not.

The corresponding assembly instructions are (AT&T syntax)

Test a bit (CF = bit value):

```
BT imm8, reg
BT reg, reg
BT reg, mem
```

Test and complement (CF = old bit value; new bit value = ~old bit value):

```
BTC imm8, reg
BTC reg, reg
BTC reg, mem
```

Test and reset (CF = old bit value; new bit value = 0)

```
BTR imm8, reg
BTR reg, reg
BTR reg, mem
```

Test and set (CF = old bit value; new bit value = 1)

```
BTS imm8, reg
BTS reg, reg
BTS reg, mem
```

When used against memory, it can be used atomically (only one CPU accessing that memory while doing the read / modify / write cycle.) So it can be used to create locks and semaphores.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Alexis. However I didn't full understood your code, could you elaborate a little more on that, please?

Comment: You may want to download the programmer manual reference for details. http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech+64-32_manuals You probably want this book: "Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Combined Volumes 2A, 2B, and 2C: Instruction Set Reference, A-Z". The instructions take a bit position (on the left in my samples) and a register or memory location being checked.