# Efficient single-bit negation in Fortran

Tags: binary, fortran, bit

I'm writing performance-intensive Fortran code, which has at its core a matrix-free matrix multiplication subroutine mfmult(x,y), which takes an input vector x, and returns an output vector y such that if i = i_{n-1}i_{n-2}...i_2i_1i_0 is an n-bit binary number (possibly with leading zeros), then

y(i) = sum{x(j) : j is any 1-bit negation of i}

i.e.

```
y(000) = x(001)+x(010)+x(100)
y(1101) = x(0101)+x(1001)+x(1111) + x(1100) etc.
```

What would be an efficient way to implement this? A related question is: does there exist a fast intrinsic in Fortran for single-bit negation? I've had a look at the intrinsics and https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations#Fortran, but there is no single-bit negation operation, and I worry any manual coding/branching statements will make things too slow.

Comment: Well, the CPU always accesses the whole byte anyway. You can use IBSET(), but I don't expect that to be particularly efficient. You could also use IEOR() with some particular constant.

Comment: The problem with IBSET and IBCLR is that I first need a BTEST if-statement to check if the bit is a 0 and 1 so I can pick the opposite, which I expect runs pretty slow in a huge loop. I'm not sure how I'd use IEOR(). Flipping a single-bit seems like such a fundamental operation that these methods seem like overkill. Is this just a limitation of Fortran as a language that it doesn't have this intrinsic?

Comment: If you want to call it a limitation... What is the equivalent in C or x86 assembly you think is missing in Fortran?

Comment: Thanks, the IEOR approach works really fast. In fact I was quite surprised to find that it worked even faster (about twice as fast) than using a sparse matrix to explicitly carry out the vector transformation. After doing more research I now see other languages just use this approach for bit negation as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to use the [`IEOR()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/IEOR.html) intrinsic. You must prepare the right mask first. It may seem to be indirect, but I don't think there can be anything more direct in fact, see [C / Assembly: how to change a single bit in a CPU register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806455/c-assembly-how-to-change-a-single-bit-in-a-cpu-register)

So if you have integer `i`, and you want to flip the third bit, I would really do:

```
i = ieor(i, int(b'00000100'))
```

What this will do in the x86_64 assembly is

```
xorl    $4, the_register_holding_i
```

If you want to flip multiple bits in that integer it is better to prepare the mask accordingly and call `IEOR()` just once.

Note that the CPU always works with the whole byte (at least) or more efficiently with a whole word, there are no instructions which would only take an address of a bit and manipulate only that one. You don't have to worry that your are accessing the whole 32-bit integer, because you have a 32-bit or 64-bit processor. The instruction set is prepared to work with 32-bit and 64-bit integers efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

This should be efficient:

```
program test
  implicit none
  integer :: filter(0:31)
  data filter / &
    b'00000000000000000000000000000001', &
    b'00000000000000000000000000000010', &
    b'00000000000000000000000000000100', &
    b'00000000000000000000000000001000', &
    b'00000000000000000000000000010000', &
    b'00000000000000000000000000100000', &
    b'00000000000000000000000001000000', &
    b'00000000000000000000000010000000', &
    b'00000000000000000000000100000000', &
    b'00000000000000000000001000000000', &
    b'00000000000000000000010000000000', &
    b'00000000000000000000100000000000', &
    b'00000000000000000001000000000000', &
    b'00000000000000000010000000000000', &
    b'00000000000000000100000000000000', &
    b'00000000000000001000000000000000', &
    b'00000000000000010000000000000000', &
    b'00000000000000100000000000000000', &
    b'00000000000001000000000000000000', &
    b'00000000000010000000000000000000', &
    b'00000000000100000000000000000000', &
    b'00000000001000000000000000000000', &
    b'00000000010000000000000000000000', &
    b'00000000100000000000000000000000', &
    b'00000001000000000000000000000000', &
    b'00000010000000000000000000000000', &
    b'00000100000000000000000000000000', &
    b'00001000000000000000000000000000', &
    b'00010000000000000000000000000000', &
    b'00100000000000000000000000000000', &
    b'01000000000000000000000000000000', &
    b'10000000000000000000000000000000'/
  integer :: a
  integer :: k

  ! Number whose single-bit negations should be found
  a = b'1101'

  do k=0,31
    print *, ieor(a,filter(k))
  enddo

end
```

Comment: Just a style comment - data is a little old fashioned, I'd initialise filter in the declaration, and make it a parameter as well