# Pthread Program Counter

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, program-counter

Using pthreads for C, is there a way to access the program counter/instruction pointer for specific threads?

Example:

```
void *thread_main(void *arg) {
  long thread = (long)arg;

  lock (thread);
  ***print (thread.pc);*** 
  critical_section (thread);
  ***print (thread.pc);***  
  unlock (thread);

  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a cross-platform solution, or do you just need this to work on a specific platform (e.g. Windows, etc).

Comment: C has no concept of a "program counter". You can use the `__FILE__`, `__func__` and `__LINE__` macros to identify which part of the code is currently executing.

Comment: @i_am_jorf 
I have a MacOS and a Debian machine. So either would be acceptable :)

Comment: Would writing a function which picks up return address from stack solve your problem?

Comment: You can access registers using [these](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3022046/74815) solutions, but you'll need to do it on the thread you care about, as far as I know.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote here.  This is a legitimate programming question that undoubtedly has a solution.

Comment: in general, the parameter to a thread should be a pointer, not a value,  so this line: `long thread = (long)arg;` should be: `long thread = (long*)arg;`

Comment: when asking runtime questions, such as this one, post the actual input(s) post the actual outputs, post a short (cleanly compiles) code that still exhibits the problem.  BTW: just what is your problem?

Comment: @user3629249 I create the threads as:
 pthread_create(&pid[i], NULL, &thread_body, (void*)((long)i));

Comment: OOps, I made an error, the line: `long thread = (long)arg;` should be: `long thread = *(long*)arg`.  because should be passing a pointer, not the actual value. Per your comment, should create the thread with: `pthread_creat( *pid[i], NULL, &thread_body, &i );`  assuming the `i` is actually a `long` variable/  Among other reasons, because a `long` might not be the same size as a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `backtrace()`; it is supported on both your platforms.

```
    #include <execinfo.h>
    ....
        void * pc;
        backtrace(&pc, 1);
    ....
```

See `man 3 backtrace` for details. Beware that all threads running the same `thread_main` will report the same `pc`.