# How are registers used in C?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Like the CR3 register which is used to point to the page directory. Linux also uses paging and is written in C, but how are these registers used in C (how to select a particular register using C)?

Comment: if you want to use registers directly, you need to code in assembly language.

Comment: and how macro are initialized  ?(i mean i have read some macros to select registers) and i haven't seen assembly language in source code of paging in linux. how does that code work?

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve. Normally you do not need to use CPU registers in C,BTW the C language C doesn't specify how registers can be accessed. But many compilers have extensions that allow you to address directly CPU registers.

Comment: @karansharma Then you didn't look carefully enough. For writing cr3 there's a function called `write_cr3` in arch/x86/include/system.h. It has inline assembler. (this is on the particular version of linux I had laying around, maybe this is different in other versions)

Comment: thanks Art, i got that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to access 32-bit registers in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022046/is-it-possible-to-access-32-bit-registers-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

The C language provides no way to access specific processor registers. This is all up to the compiler.

To access specific registers you would have to write at least this part of your code in assembler.

Comment: I mean your answer does not answer the question, you should post it as a comment.

Comment: @MichaelWalz - But it does answer the question. The OP asked in the scope of pure C. Pure C doesn't allow for it. Hence this is the answer. Being short doesn't detract from it.

Comment: @StoryTeller OK, maybe, I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @SisterFister I deleted my comment, you may delete your's as well.

Comment: @StoryTeller because you're right  after all., I shouldn't have posted it in first place.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I got your point, this answer does not cover all aspects, but I wanted to write the answer from the C perspective and not from GGC inline asm perspective... Also Serge already gave a better answer...

Answer (score 4):

The registers you are talking about are not a property of the language but the property of the hardware on which you run your programs. I believe that you are talking about an x86 type hardware. cr0-4 and orther specific regs are a property of the operating system and are managed by it, including paging table.

So, the language does not provide a way to access those hw-specific registers. The only way is to write an assembly code (hardware-specific) to manipulate them. The only thing which the language provides is the `asm()` operator which allows to insert assembly code in the program.

Comment: `__asm__` is an *extension* provided by a specific implementation; it is not part of the standard C language definition.

Comment: @JohnBode right, the standard one is `asm()`. I fixed it.

Comment: `asm` is listed under J.5.10 as a common extension, but it is not part of the core language or library.  As it says in J.5/1: "The following extensions are widely used in many systems, but are not portable to all
implementations."

Comment: @JohnBode it is defined in `10.4 The asm declaration`. It is enough to make it a part of the language, i think. Though it is `conditionally supported`.

Comment: Which document are you looking at?  I don't see that anywhere in the [C 2011 online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: oops, sorry, i looked in the c++ standard by coincidence.  But here is the workding from  `n1570 ISO/IEC 9899:201x J.5.10 The asm keyword` *The asm keyword may be used to insert assembly language directly into the translator
output (6.8). The most common implementation is via a statement of the form:*

Comment: The Linux kernel is written in GNU C, not ISO C.  It also makes use of `__attribute__((noinline))`, `__attribute__((always_inline))`, `__builtin_expect()`, and various other GNU C features (mostly for performance, though.  `asm` is the GNU extension that really lets the kernel do what it needs to do, including compiler memory barriers using `asm volatile("" ::: "memory")`.  Linux depends heavily on the exact semantics on `asm` in GNU C, not just the ability to inline a custom instruction occasionally.  Porting it to MSVC's (obsolete/bad) `__asm {}` syntax would be hard.

Answer (score 3):

Standard C does not provide any facility to directly access processor registers.  Some implementations *may* provide extensions that allow you to embed assembly code in your C code (such as the [`asm`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) extension provided by gcc).

Generally speaking, if you need direct access to a processor register (or other hardware-specific location), you'd write that routine in assembler and link it into the larger program.